# Strongly Typed List For Combo Box Returning MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

OK, so theres been plenty of posts on this type of error, but nothing specific enough for me to narrow down the issue.

```
SqlConnection con = null;
        List<State> list = new List<State>();
        try
        {
            con = Common.openConnection(Common.connectionString);
            string sql = "Select * from State order by state";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                State m = new State(int.Parse(reader.GetValue(0).ToString()),reader.GetString(1), reader.GetString(2), int.Parse(reader.GetValue(3).ToString()));
                list.Add(m);
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error:[DALStateSQL] in selectAll : " + Common.NEWLINE + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            Common.closeConnection(con);
        }
        return list;
```

This is the method that is causing problems. Im simply trying to tie it to an object data source and display it in a list box. I am getting this stack trace:

```
[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +98
System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +241
System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +69
System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.InvokeMethod(ObjectDataSourceMethod method, Boolean disposeInstance, Object& instance) +138
System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +1953
System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +97
System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.PerformSelect() +34
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +66
System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +29
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +103
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2496
```

Which tells me nothing since there is nothing in the trace which is my own code.

I have another, identical method, which works, and its just a copy paste of the method which is misbehaving. The state class itself is fairly simple:

```
private int stateId;
    private string stateCode;
    private string name;
    private int countryCode;

    public int StateId
    {
        get { return stateId; }
        set { stateId = value; }
    }

    public string StateCode
    {
        get { return stateCode; }
        set { stateCode = value; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public int CountryCode
    {
        get { return countryCode; }
        set { countryCode = value; }
    }

    public State()
    {
        this.stateId = 0;
        this.stateCode = "";
        this.name = "";
        this.countryCode = 0;
    }

    public State(int stateId, string stateCode, string name, int countryCode)
    {
        this.stateId = stateId;
        this.stateCode = stateCode;
        this.name = name;
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
    }
```

Edit: I forgot to mention the selectAll() method calls perfectly elsewhere, but breaks when trying to bind it to an object data source. .....?

Comment: The error message says it all: "No parameterless constructor defined for this object.". The platform is trying to construct a class (I presume your datasource) using a parameterless constructor, but there is none present.

Comment: Just cleaning up some old posts.

This was actually due to the restrictions on the permissions for the Constructor access. The Singleton implementation of this class dictacted a private constructor, which the datasource for the page didnt play well with